# Passing a table to run in execute command in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write multiple statements given below

```
EXECUTE ssc.iqv_calculation ('PWCD_PRODUCT_CATEGORY', 'PRODUCT_CATEGORY');
EXECUTE ssc.iqv_calculation ('PWCD_CONTRACTING_LOCATION', 'CONTRACTING_LOCATION');
EXECUTE ssc.iqv_calculation ('PWCD_CNTRY_INCORPORATION', 'CNTRY_INCORPORATION');
EXECUTE ssc.iqv_calculation ('PWCD_COUNTRY_OF_OPERATIONS', 'COUNTRY_OF_OPERATIONS');
EXECUTE ssc.iqv_calculation ('PWCD_XBORDER_ACTIVITY', 'XBORDER_ACTIVITY');
EXECUTE ssc.iqv_calculation ('PWCD_APPROVED_EXCHANGE', 'APPROVED_EXCHANGE');
EXECUTE ssc.iqv_calculation ('PWCD_LEGAL_STRUCTURE', 'LEGAL_STRUCTURE');
```

These are few but I need to write 100 such statements.

How can I send them in a loop given that I have a table containing two columns having the list of the two parameters.

One way is excel. How can I do it in Oracle itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
begin
    for rec in (select param1, param2 from your_table) loop
        execute immediate 'begin ssc.iqv_calculation(:1, :2); end;'
            using
            in rec.param1,
            in rec.param2;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Enjoy.